# Receiving SIGQUIT unexpectedly during runtime

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I have a multithreaded program that is using signals for the parent process to communicate with the child threads.

I set up a sigset_t to receive 3 signals, SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, and SIGQUIT. Each of my threads call the same function where they sit in an infinite loop which contains a switch statement to handle the return value from a sigwait call. For some reason, my threads are randomly being sent the SIGQUIT signal for an unknown reason during execution where I am not sending the threads the signal from my parent thread or during run-time. Is there anything that I should be looking for to correct this mishap?

My signal handler is structured something like this:

```
for(;;){

if(sigwait(&signal_set,&return_val)) std::cout<<"\nsigwait error";

switch(return_val){

case: SIGUSR1

//do stuff

case: SIGUSR2

//do stuff

case: SIGQUIT

}


}
```

I am programming in Xcode on OSX.

Comment: Not some silly oversight like forgetting to put a break in your switch statement?

Comment: `case: SIGUSR1` is of course illegal syntax. It's always better to cut and paste your real code, otherwise you just get people fixing the mistakes you made in transcribing your code.

Comment: Are you using `sigwait` inside the actual signal handler? You are aware that it's not considered a "safe function" to call inside a signal handler?